# Octave/Matlab - Subplotting figures with existing plots

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

My Octave workflow is the following:

I have tons of data to process, and lots of plots to generate. For each plot,
I have a function that does all the work, generates its own plot and returns the handle of this plot for future modifications (if needed). Something like this:

```
function [h,p] = processData_and_generatePlot_A(datainput)
       %%.....
       h = figure();
       p = plot(h, ...)
       %%....
end
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is a script calling all this functions, collecting all the figures, and trying to combine all of them in only one figure (i.e., each plot generated should be a subplot in a new figure).

So, the questions are:

- Is it possible to pass the plot handler to the `subplot` function, so the plot is printed instead of generate a new one?
- If not, is there any way to insert existing plots into a new figure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The thing is, you are generating a new figure. The best advice one can give in this cases (at least for the future), **clearly** separate `processData` and `generatePlot`. Your life will be easier. In general, if you can describe a function as `do_Y_and_X`, its probably not good design. You want functions `X` and `Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method for merging plots in different figures as subplot of a new figure actually exists. What afraids me is that you have *"lots of plots to generate"*, so you must define a criterion for splitting the existing plots into `N` figures in order to avoid cramming all of them into a single figure.

The aforementioned approach involves the usage of the [copyobj](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) function, and here is an example that you can easily modify following your needs:

```
f1 = figure();
x1 = -10:0.1:10;
y1 = sin(x1);
p1 = plot(x1,y1,'r');

f2 = figure();
x2 = -10:0.1:10;
y2 = cos(x2);
p2 = plot(x2,y2,'r');

pause(5);

f3 = figure();
sub1 = subplot(1,2,1);
sub2 = subplot(1,2,2);

copyobj(p1,sub1);
delete(f1);

copyobj(p2,sub2);
delete(f2);
```

Comment: This is the well-known problem of using very old codes that no one knows who made them but you have to use. I'm just trying to gather all the related plots in figures so there will be more sense that now.

Comment: I know this feeling since it takes up 80% of my working time. Be patient and try to optimize what you can.